# Colorbox doesn't close immediately if calling print() prior to close -- why?

Tags: jquery-plugins, colorbox

I'm using Colorbox in iframe mode, and am seeing an odd issue that I would appreciate some help in figuring out. My iframe contains a form and another iframe (which contains a preview of the content to be printed), and on my submit handler for the form, I want to invoke window.print() on the embedded iframe and then close the colorbox. My code is hooked up like so:

```
        $('#printer_friendly_form').submit(function () {
            var previewWindow = $('iframe#print_preview').get(0).contentWindow;
            setZoom($('html', previewWindow.document), 1);
            previewWindow.focus();
            previewWindow.print();
            $('#print_preview').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            parent.$.colorbox.close();
            return false;
        });
```

The "setZoom" bit is a little trick I'm doing to scale the content in the embedded iframe down for a print preview without horizontal scrollbars; prior to printing I'm setting the zoom back to 1 so it prints out properly. I've tried removing this code and it doesn't seem to impact the question at hand.

The problem I have is that on Chrome, after I dismiss Chrome's print preview dialog, it takes a good 5-8 seconds before the colorbox finally closes. If I remove the "previewWindow.print()" line, the colorbox closes immediately. From my debugging, Chrome treats print as a synchronous call, so close is called only after the print dialog disappears. But it's called immediately after, and the function returns--so I don't know how to account for the delay in actually closing.

I've also found on IE9 that the colorbox closes immediately (even before the print dialog appears, which means IE must be asynchronous). Likewise, Firefox (which also seems to be synchronous like Chrome) dismisses the colorbox immediately after the print dialog is done.

Is this a Chrome bug/"feature", or is there something else I should be doing in order to get the dialog to close immediately?

Comment: Sorry to add activity to a post almost a year old, but I'm getting this issue at the moment. I open Colorbox - click print, close the "print dialog" and I can't get rid of the colorbox without navigating away from the page...

Comment: I assume you're using the latest Chrome release? I just checked on my site and I'm not having issues with the dialog disappearing. However, I vaguely recall it happening once or twice a couple of weeks ago...I never did find any root cause; it just seemed to fix itself (perhaps with a Chrome update).

Comment: I ended up forcing a `$.fancybox.close()` when the print dialog was initialised - simple and easy fix

Answer (score 0):

That sounds frustrating.  I can't think of anything on ColorBox's end that would contribute to this, so I assume it's unrelated.  Does the same thing happen with Chrome if you execute something other than colorbox (an alert for example)?

Comment: So, I finally came back to this and it seems the problem has magically remedied itself. I forgot to check my Chrome version previously, but it's currently at 19.0.1084.46, so my guess is something in a recent update fixed the problem.